# For Sharepoint 2013, $expand and $select params does not work together

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, sharepoint-rest-api, role-assignment

For sharepoint, we are trying to get files within a given list id along with its roleAssignments information.

For this, we are using REST API
***/Lists(guid'list_ID')/items?$expand=File&$select=*,hasuniqueroleassignments***. This expands files objects in the response and also has the flag *HasUniqueRoleAssignments*, which gives information on the permission inheritance.

However, for sharepoint **2013**, the same API does not expands the File objects in the response when used with the *select* param. Hence, we need to make two API calls, first for expanding files and then to fetch information on role assigments on each of the file.

Is there any other work around or other parameter that we can use for sharepoint 2013 to get this information in one API call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, `HasUniqueRoleAssignments` is *just a flag* that tells you whether or not the item has unique permissions.

In order to get the actual permission information, you would need to also expand the `RoleAssignments` property itself:

```
_api/web/lists(guid'list-id')/items?$expand=File,RoleAssignments&$select=*,hasuniqueroleassignments
```

You still might have to add additional params to the `$select` or `$expand` in order to get information you find useful, from my quick test in Postman, expanding `RoleAssignments` results in a couple properties that have `__deferred` URIs, and the single `PrincipalId` property that actually has data, which I guess could be useful if you already know the user IDs of relevant users, or else you would have to make an additional query to get more detailed user information.

---

To address your additional question from the comments:

> i want to understand if the file is inheriting permission from its
> parent folder/list. Do we have any such property in RoleAssignments
> thats will help?

There is a property that will tell you that information, but it's not within `RoleAssignments`.  You're already getting that property - it's the `HasUniqueRoleAssignments` property itself that will tell you.

If `HasUniqueRoleAssignments` is `true`, then it is *not* inheriting permissions, it *has unique* permissions.

If `HasUniqueRoleAssignments` is `false`, then it does *not* have unique permissions, and therefore *is* inheriting permissions from a parent object, whether that be a folder, or the document library it is in, or the parent web site where the document library is.

If `HasUniqueRoleAssignments` is `false` you can check the `FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject` property to find out exactly which object the file is inheriting its permissions from.

Comment: Thats correct! however, i want to understand if the file is inheriting permission from its parent folder/list. Do we have any such property in RoleAssignments thats will help?

Comment: @NidhiTeli updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This really helped understanding the hierarchy for an objects in sharepoint.